# Editing an already imported module

Tags: powershell, module, import-module

Before importing my powershell module `(MyModule.psm1)`, I have written one function in it:

```
Function T1()
{
    Write-Host "T1 is just called" -ForegroundColor red
}
```

In my `MyModule.psd1`:

```
@{
    PowerShellVersion = '2.0'
    PowerShellHostName = ''
    PowerShellHostVersion = '2.0'
    RequiredModules = @()
    ScriptsToProcess = @()
    NestedModules = @()
    FunctionsToExport = '*'
    CmdletsToExport = '*'
    VariablesToExport = '*'
    ModuleList = @()
    FileList = @()
}
```

This is imported fine, when I copied both files in:

`C:\Users\fwaheed\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyModule`

and I'm able to run `T1` in my PowerShell session. But now I wanted to add a new function in same module i.e.:

```
Function T2()
{
    Write-Host "Its now T2.." -ForegroundColor red
}
```

Even after restarting my PowerShell session, it never recognize `T2`, however `T1` is still working. How can I edit my already imported module such that changes are available immediately.

Comment: `import-module mymodule -force` is not enough?

Comment: Tried that as well, but in vain.. :(

Comment: Thanks buddy...
Just removed the module, Imported again and tried with 
"import-module MyModule -force"
And it worked by adding 4 more functions...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Once a module has been imported, changes to it are not recognised since the module is loaded into memory.  However, I've always been able to do a `Remove-Module foo`, followed by an `Import-Module foo` to load new functions.

All that said, your PSD1 file doesn't look right.  It should have a `ModuleToProcess` field set to 'MyModule.psm1'.  Then when you do `Import-Module MyModule` or `Import-Module .\mymodule.psd1`, PowerShell will find & load the associated `MyModule.psm1` file.  I wonder if that is causing you to run afoul of some caching PowerShell does?

Comment: Keith, I only posted part of psd1 file which is setting up  the Export methodology. It does have ModuleToProcess, or it won't be able to import my module script, Right?

Comment: That is sort of correct.  You have to have that entry to load the PSM1 when your PSD1 is imported.  However, you can import-module mymodule.psm1 which bypasses your PSD1.  I'm pretty sure though if you do import-module mymodule it will process the PSD1 which would then instruct PowerShell that MyModule.psm1 needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 58):

Use the `-Force` command with the `Import-Module` and it will reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the only solution that worked for me so far, in which you [configure vscode to run a new session on each debug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654#issuecomment-439557319), I didnt find any other solution to work and debug Powershell classes.

[image]