# How do I force powershell to reload a custom module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

I have created a module 'ActiveDirectory.psm1' which contains a class in powershellv5. I am importing that module in another file called 'test.ps1' and then calling a method from the class.

test.ps1 contains the following:

```
using module '\\ser01\Shared\Scripts\Windows Powershell\modules\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory.psm1'

Set-StrictMode -version Latest;

$AD = [ActiveDirectory]::New('CS');
$AD.SyncGroupMembership($True);
```

It all works as expected BUT when I make a change to ActiveDirectory.psm1 & save the changes they aren't reflected immediately. i.e. if ActiveDirectory.psm1 contains:

```
write-verbose 'do something';
```

If I change that to

```
write-verbose 'now the script does something else';
```

the output remains 'do something'

I'm guessing it has stored the module in memory and doesn't reload it therefore missing the changes I have made. What command do I need to run to load the most recent saved version of the module?

Comment: `Import-Module ActiveDirectory -force` maybe? See [Powershell: Editing an already imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19045315)

Comment: I've created this issue to address the problem of the `using module` statement not reloading the module after changes have been made to it. Please go thumbs up it to up-vote it. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing an already imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045315/editing-an-already-imported-module)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As suggested by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), you can try pass the `-Force` flag:

```
Import-Module ... -Force
```

Or if that does not work try to explicitly remove it and then reimport with:

```
Remove-Module
```

Comment: Import-Module -Force does not seem to have any effect on classes though.
There's no way of doing "using module MyModule -Force" that I can tell. Like doing Add-Type with a C# class, they appear to persist for the entire session. I'd love to know a way round that

Comment: I've created this issue to address the problem of the `using module` statement not reloading the module after changes have been made to it. Please go thumbs up it to up-vote it. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654

Comment: Yes!! I was closing my whole powershell session like a dummy

Answer (score 6):

From what I've gathered. Import-Module does not import classes. You have to use the "using module " and it has to be in the first line of your script. On top of that problem, the classes appear to be "cached" in some esoteric way that precludes any uninstall-module or remove-module options. I've found I basically need to restart my powershell terminal to clear it.

If classes are not involved use import-module OR install-module. In both cases you can do a get-modules -all or get-installedmodule and then remove-module or uninstall-module. You want to make sure you look for all versions and pipe that to remove/uninstall to ensure you wipe everything out.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same issue. I have a module with a class but it is not reloaded with Remove-Module, Import-Module. I have to restart the PowerShell session to get updates, etc. Probably same issue as mentioned by matthew-heimlich

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming across this issue, see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2505

It seems that there is a known long-standing bug regarding importing of modules that are anything above rudimentary level in complexity (for example, I have a module with a single class and class method that fails to update).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old post, but the reason non-script modules don't work without reloading PowerShell is due to .NET backing.  When an actual class/type or assembly is loaded into memory for .NET, you cannot remove it.  Alternatively, you can create a namespace based on the version of the module you are loading, and as long as the refreshed module references the newly defined classes/types within that new namespace, all will be well.  The original classes will still remain in memory, but for refresh purposes this is the only way to get around that issue.  For assemblies, any referenced classes (directly or indirectly) with changes would also need to be in a new namespace.

Example (simplified for purposes to demonstration, type information can be loaded separately from a DLL using the PSD1 format):

```
    function Invoke-MyMethod {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$Title,
        [DateTime]$SomeDate
    )
    BEGIN {
        if($null -eq (Get-TypeData 'MyNamespace.SomeClass')) {
            Add-Type @"
using System;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class SomeClass {
        public SomeClass() {
            this.Other = new SomeOtherClass();
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public SomeOtherClass Other { get; set; }
        public string SomeMethod() {
            string returnValue = String.Format("Title: {0}\r\n\t{1}", this.Title, this.Other.SomeOtherMethod());
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
    public class SomeOtherClass {
        public DateTime MyTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherMethod() {
            return this.MyTimestamp.ToString("g");
        }
    }
}
"@
        }
    }
    PROCESS {
        $someThing = New-Object 'MyNamespace.SomeClass'
        $someThing.Title = $Title
        $someThing.Other.MyTimestamp = $SomeDate
        $someThing.SomeMethod()
    }
}
```

This can be invoked using:

```
Import-Module Test
Invoke-MyMethod -Title 'test' -SomeDate (Get-Date)
# Results in something like this:
# Title: test
#     12/6/2023 7:43 AM
```

Then you make an update to include a dateformat parameter (notice the namespace ends with "v2" and that internal classes to that namespace don't care since they are already in the right namespace):

```
    function Invoke-MyMethod {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$Title,
        [DateTime]$SomeDate,
        [string]$DateFormat = 'g'
    )
    BEGIN {
        if($null -eq (Get-TypeData 'MyNamespacev2.SomeClass')) {
            Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespacev2 {
    public class SomeClass {
        public SomeClass() {
            this.Other = new SomeOtherClass();
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public SomeOtherClass Other { get; set; }
        public string SomeMethod(string format) {
            string returnValue = String.Format("Title: {0}\r\n\t{1}", this.Title, this.Other.SomeOtherMethod(format));
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
    public class SomeOtherClass {
        public DateTime MyTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherMethod(string format) {
            return this.MyTimestamp.ToString(format);
        }
    }
}
"@
        }
    }
    PROCESS {
        $someThing = New-Object 'MyNamespacev2.SomeClass'
        $someThing.Title = $Title
        $someThing.Other.MyTimestamp = $SomeDate
        $someThing.SomeMethod($DateFormat)
    }
}
```

This can be invoked (without closing PowerShell) using:

```
Import-Module Test -Force
Invoke-MyMethod -Title 'test' -SomeDate (Get-Date) -DateFormat 'd'
# Results in something like this:
# Title: test
#     12/6/2023
```

It's worth noting that you can still create and reference the old type while the PowerShell session hasn't closed:

```
$data = New-Object 'MyNamespace.SomeClass'
$data.Title = 'abc'
$data.Other.MyTimestamp = '2023-12-06'
$data.SomeMethod()
# Results in something like this:
# Title: abc
#     12/6/2023 12:00 AM
```