# How to pass $variable that contains hyphen in its value as a parameter to another function

Tags: powershell

As an example I have a module called `web-utils`, let's say I do some updates to it and I need to reload it like "[module reload explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426477/how-do-i-force-powershell-to-reload-a-custom-module/39433203)". I have created a function

```
function Module-Reload([string]$name) {
  Remove-Module -Name $name -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
  Import-Module -Name $name -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

which throws an error as module name contain a hyphen, the question is: is there a way automatically escape hyphen in variables value? or is there another way of passing such parameters? As `Import-Modules -Force web-utils` works flawlessly only when it's typed manually in CLI. In case of doing it via function results in the following:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'web`-utils' was not loaded because no
valid module file was found in any module directory.
At WindowsPowerShell\Aliases.ps1:35 char:3
+   Import-Module -Name $value -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (web`-utils:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having hyphens in a module name. PowerShell throws the error shown in your question b/c it cannot find a module named ``web`-utils`` (with a backtick in the name).

Comment: The string ``"web`-utils"`` reduces to `"web-utils"` *if* given as a literal, even though `-` does not actually need escaping. You likely have an `\`` too many somewhere where it's not actually required, or else a string is obtained from some source that doesn't go through PowerShell's parsing.